# C++ encode multiple values into 1 float

Tags: c++

I only have so many variables exposed through shaders. One of those values is right now for color, but I'm bastardizing it right now and in the shader using it for something else. However I need more. Right now I'm using the x & y values for index values to lookup a subtexture on 1 big texture, which the shader will offset to. The z value of the color is for how many subtextures fit on the width of the big main texture. Because they are index values they only really need to be ints and even char up to 256 would be fine.

Now I want to be able to provide a scale value and a subset offset from the subtexture to give me full control. Since I'll always need the z float value of the color and need it to be a float that variable is out. That leaves me with x, y, a (alpha) float values. Is there any way I could encode byte values inside these so that when I decode them in the shader x actually stores 2 values, y stores 2 values, and alpha stores 2 values?

I hope that made sense. I want to be able to encode values into a floating point variable via my game code, then decode them in the shader and use them in the shader. Is this possible and if so what kind of value restrictions would we be looking at and how would you do it?

Comment: Evil hack: `float f1, f2; double d; *(uint64_t *)&d = (*(uint32_t *)&f1 << 32) | *(uint32_t *)&f2;` - but why would you ***ever*** do this?

Comment: This would probably come with quite a performance penalty, and as for the precision, you should know that shaders often use low-precision floats, so you will see more degradation than you expect. Also I don't think shaders support bitwise operators, which you would need. If any of your values are discrete then you might stand a chance

Comment: The models are instanced to save memory. Their geometry and material are shared. The unique model values are position/scale/rotation/color. This is a good thing for performance, however it makes other challenges like reusing the same model with different materials. To get around this I make subtextures and put them into 1 big texture. In order to align the texture I want I use the color vec4 value to tell the shader what texture I want. This works well, but now I want to scale and offset within the subtexture so need more values to get to the shader so it can do it.

Comment: you could reserve a part of the texture for this information and upload that part whenever the data changes. This would give some performance penalty as you need to upload texture data and use the texture units to retrieve the information, but it might be useful in your situation.